# Take python file output and read output into excel

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I'm using Google NLP to extract entities from text. Once I run the code in my terminal, I receive an output that looks like this.

[Python File Ouput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VW9s5.png)

I am having difficulty figuring out how to create a data frame that takes "Name, Type, Salience, Wiki URL, and MID" as a header and inputs the data to the right into an excel file.

I was thinking I could use something like this:

```
import xlwt

x = (("a",1),("b",2),("c",3))

wb = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = wb.add_sheet("test")
for i, row in enumerate(x):
    for j, col in enumerate(row):
        ws.write(i, j, col)
wb.save("sample.xls")
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post what you would like your output to look like in excel? You can use to pandas to create excel files

Comment: also, what is the ouput file type? just a text file that looks like that?

Answer (score 0):

Like Anna commented above, you can use pandas to write to excel. The tuples you provided can be written to excel as below (passed as a list). If your Google NLP-file is in JSON format, you can use pandas as well.

```
import pandas as pd
x = (("a",1),("b",2),("c",3))
file_df = pd.DataFrame(list(x))
file_df.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```